# Parse save method gives 400 error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

The following code doesn't save anything to the database:

```
    var UserObject = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var objectid = object.id;
    var secondQuery = new Parse.Query(UserObject);
    secondQuery.get(objectid, {
        success: function(userObject) {
            alert(userObject.get("fbId"));

             userObject.set("provider_access_token", access_token);
             userObject.set("provider_refresh_token", refresh_token);
             userObject.set("provider_token_expire", expires_in);

            userObject.save(null, {
                error: function(error){
                    alert(error.message + error.code);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            alert("Error:" + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure why, but it does give me an 400 HTTP error. What am I doing wrong?

I've checked that all my variables are set and correct (the alert works just fine).

Comment: Sure you can pass only an ID in query.get(objectid ? I would expect an HTTP API to take an URI-String like: "/apiendpoint/".intval(objectid).. Also, check if you havent missed a function() { in front of that next {.

Comment: EDIT: 400 HTTP error means: A server has been connected but the request was malformed. This modul seems to perform an AJAX request. (Sorry, *404* is "resource not found")

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt yes, Parse documentation says so. But that is not the problem, because it actually retrieves the correct user object.. The alert works just fine.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone this is the method provided by Parse, so I'm not sure how that could be the problem..

Comment: @Ande I don't know that module. An HTTP error implies that somewhere in the background a request has been done. Maybe the code is missing to specify a URL?

Comment: Which alert gives you the 400 ? And what for the 3 r's in errror ?

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt all alerts are working fine, but no data is saved, so when I open up the developer console in Google Chrome I see that there is an 400 error.

Comment: Are you aware that you do `query.get` instead of probably `secondQuery.get`?

Comment: @metadings no, I wasn't aware. Thanks! I've updated that but it still gives me the 400 error.

Comment: well you should start to use `console.log` instead of the ugly alert! out of the console you can click into your script, copy some output and have a deeper look into the DOM and the network transport (400 and what?)

Comment: @metadings I've changed everything to console.log. What information would you need so I can provide it? I don't see any other options to click through.

Comment: what is the 400 errors' message?

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with your problem, but in userObject.save you've typed "errror", is that a typo?

Comment: @JuanGarcia sorry, typo.

Comment: @metadings I'm now getting something from the error function in save, I think I'll find the solution myself. I will post it as an answer!

Comment: if it was a typo you probably wasn't getting the error that specifies why it wasn't saving

Comment: @JuanGarcia you're right, so now luckily I'm getting the error. Thanks for pointing it out, when you stare at your code for so long you become blind for these kind of mistakes.

Comment: It happends to everybody, I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Juan Guarcia who pointed out that I had an type which led to the error not showing up. After fixing that my problem was easily solved.

The error I was getting was the following:

Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError206

Which means that user objects cannot be altered without using the master key of my application. However, this isn't supported inside the Parse Javascript SDK, only in the Cloud Code.

So I need to move the function to the Cloud Code and then save from there. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: errror > error
Fixing this will give you the real error of why isn't getting saved